Budgie 24.04 lock screen not working
I recently did a fresh install of 24.04 Budgie after I was having problems with 22.04 Budgie and VirtualBox. While my lock screen worked fine on 22.04, it no longer works at all on 24.04.
That is, I cannot use Super+L, I cannot click on the power menu and click Lock, and I cannot just wait for a few minutes to pass for my screen saver to lock it.
I see there are a few solutions for 22.04 and earlier versions but I would assume (hope) any underlying issues would have been resolved in 24.04.
Anyone have any solutions for 24.04?

I found an answer here (meant for 22.04) which worked on 24.04.
sudo apt purge gnome-shell-common

So, I guess the underlying conflict between gnome-shell and Budgie are still in 24.04. Hopefully, they will resolve it in future versions.

To be clear, I did have to reboot for this change to take effect.
